# What fuse can I use to replace this old glass tube fuse?

Tags: short-circuit, fuses

With what can I replace this old glass tube fuse?

Original fuse: glass tube fuse with the engravings "UEC 10A."

It is from a industrial motorized device perhaps 15-20 years old from Japan.

I have tried F10AL250V fuses, but it blew these new fuses. I don't think it's a problem with the device (e.g., a short circuit) as I have a second, identical version of this device that also blows these fuses. I cannot find documentation for this device.

Below is the original blown fuse that worked with the machine. 6x30mm.

[image: Original blown fuse that worked with the machine. 6x30mm.]

Comment: Have you tried slow blow not fast blow fuses?

Comment: Slow blow fuses are a must for starting any size of motor.

Comment: I have not -- will this fry the device if it doesn't use slow blow fuses?

Comment: It will just likely blow the fast acting fuses quite fast.

Comment: If I try a slow blow fuse and the device doesn't use slow blow fuses, will it destroy the device?

Comment: What are the fuse dimensions?

Comment: fuse dimensions are 6x30mm

Comment: It sounds like you have a second unit with an intact original fuse. Please edit into your question a photo of the good fuse (or if not, of the original blown fuse). If it has a glass envelope, we can probably verify if it was slow blow.

Comment: The second unit did not have a fuse, but I attached an image of the blown fuse that worked with the machine -- does it look like possibly a time delay/slow blow fuse?

Answer (score 2):

Fast-action glass fuses are suitable for resistive applications, that do not involve high switch-on surge currents.

Slow-action glass fuses are intended for handling high switch-on surge currents, drawn at motor start or power supply switch-on.

The F10AL250V is a fast-action fuse.

Your motor control application requires a T10AL250VP slow-action fuse.

Comment: I attached an image of the blown fuse that worked with the machine -- does it look like possibly a time delay/slow blow fuse?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a slow-blow fuse. There do not appear to be medium blow fuses currently easily available in that size and rating.

Slow blow is *typically* adequate to protect wiring and things like motors and transformers, but may allow more damage to your equipment if something else is wrong (for example, to semiconductors).

Unless there is a lot more information available and the knowledge to apply it, I don't see a whole lot of other options open, other than the obvious one of trying to source an exact replacement from some unknown Asian manufacturer (who might well be defunct or  have changed hands one more times by now).

I **don't** suggest increasing the fuse rating and staying with fast-blow, that's for sure.

The fuse pictured does not look like a slow-blow to me (typically they have a coil or spring like structure inside) but it may be sufficiently different from other fast-blow fuses to work whereas the ones you can buy don't.

Comment: Thank you. I think the Asian manufacturer is long gone unfortunately. Does it look like a "medium blow" fuse? I've never even heard of those -- were those more common decades ago?

Comment: @myflow They're listed now, but I don't see any in stock at Digikey in your size and rating. I didn't look very hard.

Comment: I did try a slow blow (T10A250V) and unfortunately both machines blew those fuses. I can only conclude both machines independently acquired shorts, which surprises me as I was informed the second machine was operational. Are there any other explanations aside from both having shorts?

Comment: Slow blow fuse of the original rating failing instantly is an indication something is seriously wrong. It might not be a direct short, but something is causing a large overload current.

Comment: I see. Would it be possible to give some examples of what might cause a large current overload so I can investigate that possibility?

Comment: Jammed motor rotor (draws stall current). Failed MOV or capacitor across the line (sort-of a short but maybe not that low resistance). Shorted turn in a transformer or motor (draws much higher than usual current, but not a direct short).